# In the 2nd temple period would "the Samaritans" refer to the same group as "the lost sheep of the house of Israel"?

Tags: northern-kingdom

I have read various articles about Samaritans:

http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13058-samaria
http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13059-samaritans

However, I'm still not clear if Samaritans are the same group as "the lost sheep of the house of Israel". I'm taking "the lost house of Israel" to refer to "the descendants of the northern kingdom".

Comment: In editions of the Talmud controlled ‎by ‎censors, the term “Samaritan” (=כותי) is used to refer to a ‎Jewish ‎infidel, ‎especially ‎applied ‎to ‎Jewish-Christians see https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/מין_-_מיניקה  under מין III.

Comment: That was a very helpful resource, thanks.